# Why is a Different/Anonymous Github Account Pushing to My Repositories?

Tags: git, github

Someone else's Github account shows up in my commit history when I push to my github repositories from my terminal. The commited changes are mine but the account is not.

This issue does not show up on gitlab, only in github.

The account shown in the screenshot is not mine and I do not know the account owner.

How can reset `jackmwa`s account back to my name?

Note:
I have checked both `git config --get user.name` and `git config --get user.email` which are **correct** and do not equal to `jackmwa`.

`jackmwa` is an existing and different github user than my own.

[image]

Comment: Use `git config` to check or set your user name.  https://alvinalexander.com/git/git-show-change-username-email-address/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resetting git --global values did not solve the problem since the values were correct already.

I solved it by downloading the Github Desktop interface and logging in from there.

Answer (score 0):

1. open your `Git CMD`
2. type `git config --global user.name`
3. it should give you your current username
4. to change it, just type `git config --global user.name "<new_name_here>"`
5. this will change your username when you commit to any other repo in the future